# Google spreadsheets отображать символ вместо содержимого ячейки

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Можно ли сделать так, что бы во всех непустых ячейках определенного диапазона вместо их значения отображался символ `+`, но при этом в формулах использовались бы реальные значения ячеек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделить нужные ячейки.

Вкладка *Формат-Число-Другие форматы-Выбрать_числовой_формат*, в верхнем окошке вписать **+**, *Применить*